# delay the on("click") event

Tags: javascript

I have this code

```
$("input").on('keyup', function () {
 $("block"),slideDown("slow")......
```

The problem is taht when I write fast the block will do the "animation" again and agin much slower than I write

Is there another event I can use to only run the code "after I'm finished writing" lets say, I stop writing and then it taks 500ms and then the code is executed.

Comment: Could you just use the `change` event which will fire when the `input` loses focus and its value has changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this is what I've used before:

```
$(input).keyup(onKeyUp);

/**
 * Handler for the keyup event
 */
function onKeyUp() {
    //reset
    clearTimeout(myTimer);

    myTimer = setTimeout(otherFunction, 500);
}
```

Now otherFunction will be called after 500 milliseconds, but on each keyup event this timer will be reset.

Comment: You should not pass strings to `setTimeout`; it uses `eval()` behind the scenes which is ***evil***! Instead, simply do `setTimeout(otherFunction, 500);`

Answer (score 1):

```
function throttle(fn, time ){
    var timer = 0;
    return function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout($.proxy(fn, this), time);
    };
}

$("input").on('keyup', throttle(function () {
    $("block").slideDown("slow")
},500));
```

The throttle returns a new function that calls the old function once 500 milliseconds have elapsed since the function was last called.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use...

```
function slideDown(){
   ...
}    
// call
setTimeout(function(){ slideDown(); }, 1000);
```

Comment: You just suffered from W3Schools: don't pass strings to `setTimeout`. Moreover, your code simply delays the function - it doesn't take "stop writing" into account.